# how to fech list of classic virtual machines using ARM

Tags: java, azure, azure-java-sdk

I'm using the latest java SDK for azure.
When I fetch all VMs, I'm not getting VMs from the Virtual Machines (classic)

```
ServiceClientCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(client, tenant, key, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
Azure azure = Azure.authenticate(credentials).withSubscription(subscriptionId);

PagedList<VirtualMachine> vms = azure.virtualMachines().list();
```

Answer (score 0):

@ElroieRoash, Per my experience, according to the REST API [`List the resources in a subscription`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790567.aspx) in ARM, I think the feasible way with ARM to list the classic VMs is that list all resources in the subscription and filter them with the resource type.

The resource type of classic virtual machine in ARM is `Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines`.

So you just need to use the function `list()` of the class [`Subcriptions`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/resources/Subscriptions.html) to list all resources and filter the resources which type is `Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines`.

Meanwhile, I think the more clear way is that directly use the rest api with the parameter `filter` below. please refer to the section [`Common parameters and headers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790569.aspx#bk_common).

```
$filter=resourceType eq Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines
```